# Datatables <thead> dropdown filter not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm putting the dropdown filter in `<thead></thead>`. But it can't function properly. The search filter in my website works perfectly but not the dropdown filter. I even checked the html code for `<option><select>` compared to the example in [here](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html). When I select one `<option>`, the table recognizes it as unmatched value, all rows missing.

Here's a screenshot of the table together with html inspector:

[image]

Here is my `<select>` dropdown html code:

```
<option value=""></option>
<option value="SK Ambong">SK Ambong</option>
<option value="SK Dudar">SK Dudar</option>
<option value="SK Kitou">SK Kitou</option>
```

Here's my JS code:

```
$('table').DataTable({
    ordering: false,
    initComplete: function () {
        const nonSearchableColNo = [1, 6, 7, 8];
        var api = this.api();

        // For dropdown column
        api.columns(2).every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( data, j ) {
                optionVal = data.match(/SK [A-Z]\w+/g);
                select.append( '<option value="'+optionVal+'">'+optionVal+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datatables.net [documentation](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) (and your code) matches on the *full string*, so that would be "SK Dudar 1", but you're getting SK+[word], eg "SK Dudar" (as also shown in your `<option>`).

`"^SK Dudar$"` does not match with `"SK Dudar 1"` so you get no matches.

Change

```
optionVal = data.match(/SK [A-Z]\w+/g);
```

to

```
optionVal = data;
```

to check the rest works, but may not work with what looks like an additional image (no html/datatables data provided, so can't be sure)

Or change

```
column.search(val ? '^'+val+'$' :...
```

to

```
column.search(val ? '^'+val : ''...
```

(ie remove the `$`)

Depending on what else is in that data column, you may need to change your search regex, eg

```
column.search(val ? '^'+val+'\s.?\w' : ''...
```

should also match "SK Dudar" to "SK Dudar 1", but not "SK Dudar 1 2".

You may need to move the image into a different column if it's not working, but it's not matching on HTML, rather on the `column.search` API of datatables.

Comment: I'll try working based on your suggestion first. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I managed to work it out using :
`optionVal = data.match(/SK (([a-zA-Z]\w+) *)+/g);`
instead of using regex in `column.search()`, because my `val` will get some inline html code.